# Multiple WCF service implementations at one address?

Tags: wcf

I currently have several C# service implementation classes, each of which implements several service contract interfaces. Each service implementation class is at at a separate address, but all of its service contract interfaces are at the same address.

A client that wants to use interfaces from several services currently needs to know about several addresses.

I am wondering if it is possible to have several implementation classes share an address. For instance, currently, a client might connect to Browse.svc, Data.svc, Report.svc etc. Could I reconfigure so that the client only needs to go to Service.svc?

It seems to me that the SOAP Action provides a means for WCF to tell to which service implementation class it should direct the request, so this might be possible.

I really don't want to slam all my implementation into one big service class.

The following Microsoft article talks about this sort of thing, but doesn't seem to address the issue of multiple service implementation classes.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395210.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want one service, that can respond to multiple service requests. have a look at http://davybrion.github.com/Agatha/

It's an implementation of the request/response pattern for WCF.

Comment: My attempt to understand what Agatha was in a couple of minutes wasn't successful. Perhaps I need to try harder ;-)

However, how about RoutingService? Is that the same sort of thing, or different?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517423.aspx

Comment: With the routing service, you will keep all your endpoints and create one new one for your routing service. With Agatha you have one endpoint, where all service calls are received an handled. The goal of service aggregation in a routing service, is the same as Agatha. But Agatha works in a Request / Response way. Both have their pros and cons